# Get Sum with Join table

Tags: mysql, select, join, group-by

How to get `SUM` query with query `JOIN` table, I have two table, my table is `laporan` and `laporan_pengeluaran`.

**table laporan**

```
id  name    shell
9   loli    12000
10  ardi    24000
11  dian    5500
```

**table laporan_pengeluaran**

```
id  laporan_id  harga
1   9           15000
2   9           29000
3   10          7500
4   10          5000
5   11          3000
6   11          3000
```

My question, how to get SUM with join table, which group by id/name in table laporan, so i want to get result as below:

```
id  name    shell   harga
9   loli    12000   44000
10  ardi    24000   12500
11  dian    5500    6000
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You can join the two tables and then `sum(harga)` to get the result. If you know you will always have `laporan` values in your `laporan_pengeluaran` table then you can use an `INNER JOIN`:

```
select l.id,
  l.name,
  l.shell,
  sum(lp.harga) harga
from laporan l
inner join laporan_pengeluaran lp
  on l.id = lp.laporan_id
group by l.id, l.name, l.shell
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2a64a/2)

If you might have missing `laporan` values in the `laporan_pengeluaran` table then use a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
select l.id,
  l.name,
  l.shell,
  sum(lp.harga) harga
from laporan l
left join laporan_pengeluaran lp
  on l.id = lp.laporan_id
group by l.id, l.name, l.shell
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2a64a/3)

The result is:

```
| ID | NAME | SHELL | HARGA |
-----------------------------
|  9 | loli | 12000 | 44000 |
| 10 | ardi | 24000 | 12500 |
| 11 | dian |  5500 |  6000 |
```

Comment: You migth want to consider a LEFT JOIN, if not all rows in laporan are guaranteed to have related rows in laporan_pengeluaran

Comment: Hi bluefeet thanks for reply, your code is work, i have give correct answer with green check in your answer. Many2 thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  laporan.id AS id,
  laporan.name AS name,
  laporan.shell AS shell,
  IFNULL(SUM(laporan_pengeluaran.harga),0) AS harga
FROM laporan
LEFT JOIN laporan_pengeluaran ON laporan.id=laporan_pengeluaran.laporan_id
```

Comment: Hi Eugen Rieck thanks for reply, your code i not yet try, cause my problem is solved with answer below. many2 thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
SELECT
    l.id,
    l.name,
    IFNULL(lp.TCount,0) as Total
FROM laporan as l   
LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT 
                laporan_id,
                SUM(harga) as TCount
            FROM    laporan_pengeluaran
            GROUP BY laporan_id
            ) as lp ON lp.laporan_id = l.id
```

Comment: Hi raheel shan thanks for reply, your code i not yet try, cause my problem is solved with answer below. many2 thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT l.id, l.name, l.shell, SUM(lp.harga) harga 
FROM laporan l 
LEFT JOIN laporan_pengeluaran lp ON l.id = lp.laporan_id 
GROUP BY l.id;
```

Check this [**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2a64a/6)

**Output:**

```
| ID | NAME | SHELL | HARGA |
-----------------------------
|  9 | loli | 12000 | 44000 |
| 10 | ardi | 24000 | 12500 |
| 11 | dian |  5500 |  6000 |
```